# Lyapunov Exponent of the Logistic map

Tags: homework-and-exercises, chaos-theory, complex-systems

My dynamical system professor (and the textbooks we use) all claim that the Lyapunov exponent for the [Logistic](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html) [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map) with $r=4$ ($x_{n+1} = 4x_n(1-x_n)$)  is  $\log(2)$. Would someone be able to sketch the calculations for me?

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: You *do* know the solution $x_{n}=\sin^{2}(2^{n}\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x_0}))$, right?

Comment: I didn't actually. Although i still don't really see how that helps me, the only way we've been calculating the Lyapunov exponent is through the Osedelets theorem ("time" average of the logarithm of map's first derivative).

Comment: Also are you sure that's correct? from my understanding the case i proposed is chaotic so an analytical solution sounds a bit weird. Edit: i stand corrected there's a solution for r=4, interesting.

Comment: [Due diligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Solution_when_r_=_4).

Answer (score 2):

I am careful to not do your homework for you, so I will invite you to "really see" the answer, as per your comment, through the original way (1870) it was elegantly understood by the  incomparable [Schröder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%27s_equation#Applications).

Analytically continue the discrete index of the (1870) quasi-periodic solution to your recursion,
$$
_=\sin^2(2^ \arcsin(\sqrt{_0})),
$$
from *n* (the *splinter*)  to *t* (the group), a continuous trajectory,
$$
_t=\sin^2(2^t \arcsin(\sqrt{_0})),
$$
conjugate/equivalent to the tent map,
$$
\arcsin(\sqrt{x_t})= 2^t  \arcsin(\sqrt{x_0}) ~~~\leadsto \\
\arcsin(\sqrt{x_t})/\arcsin(\sqrt{x_0}) =2^t.
$$

Comment: Ah alright i think i understand how to approach it, thank you!